# How to run a .NET Core app with '<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I set up a basic C# console application in Visual Studio Code like so:

```
dotnet new console
dotnet restore
```

I then build like so:

```
dotnet build
```

Then run:

```
dotnet run
```

This all works as expected. If I change the platform target to `x86` though, I get this error when I build and run the application again:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\temp\code\testx86_2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\testx86_2.dll'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

My files:

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace testx86_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

testx86_2.csproj *before setting the platform target*:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

testx86_2.csproj *after setting the platform target*:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Versions:

- Visual Studio Code: 1.13.1
- Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core

Comment: Interesting. I was able to recreate this. `x86` is the correct PlatformTarget moniker (if you swap `x86` for something like `win-x86` which doesn't match, you'll get a list of the correct monikers). Are you running on an x64 OS? Also, does your console application have a solution file? (`dotnet new sln --name testx86_2 && dotnet sln add testx86_2.csproj` will set one up for you and add your csproj to it)

Comment: Microsoft has not made a lot of effort to promote 32-bit code, it is truly getting outdated.  Most basic mishap here is surely that you are using the wrong flavor of dotnet.exe, you need the 32-bit build of it.  Right now the download site is crashing so I can't tell if they have one available, there should be one for Windows.

Comment: @HansPassant You are correct - using the 32-bit binaries to build and run the project worked. If you would like, please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--runtime win-x86` to the run command should force the runtime to launch in 32-bit mode, even if using the the x64 version of dotnet cli.

The `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>` isn't needed, adding the switch to the run command is enough to force x86 mode. I would remove the PlatformTarget, to allow you to change between x86 / x64 more easily.